# Is there any way to distinguish keypresses of "+" on numeric keypad and "+" on "=" key in Linux Terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, console, keyboard

I mean native linux terminal which appears on Ctrl+Alt+F1. Both keys send "+" sign to terminal. In X11 terminals, like GNOME Terminal, I can connect to X11 from my console app and ask X11 for detailed keypress information to distinguish such keys. Is there any way to do something similar in Linux Terminal?